# Remove a number from a comma separated string while properly removing commas

Tags: regex, parsing, string

**FOR EXAMPLE:** Given a string... "1,2,3,4"

I need to be able to remove a given number and the comma after/before depending on if the match is at the end of the string or not.

remove(2) = "1,3,4"

remove(4) = "1,2,3"

Also, I'm using javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As jtdubs shows, an easy way is is to use a split function to obtain an array of elements without the commas, remove the required element from the array, and then rebuild the string with a join function.

For javascript something like this might work:

```
function remove(array,to_remove)
{
  var elements=array.split(",");
  var remove_index=elements.indexOf(to_remove);
  elements.splice(remove_index,1);
  var result=elements.join(",");
  return result;
}

var string="1,2,3,4,5";
var newstring = remove(string,"4"); // newstring will contain "1,2,3,5"
document.write(newstring+"<br>");
newstring = remove(string,"5"); 
document.write(newstring+"<br>"); // will contain "1,2,3,4"
```

You also need to consider the behavior you want if you have repeats, say the string is "1,2,2,4" and I say "remove(2)" should it remove both instances or just the first? this function will remove only the first instance.

Answer (score 2):

Just use multiple substitutions.

```
s/^$removed,//;
s/,$removed$//;
s/,$removed,/,/;
```

This will be easier than trying to invent a single replacement that handles all those cases.

Comment: could you perhaps explain this a bit more? i'm not very good with regex yet.

Comment: Hmm, looks like Javascript doesn't have easy interpolation into regexes.  So it could be done this way, but it will probably be easier to split into a list, process the list, and rejoin into a string (see @jtdubs).

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "1,2,3,4";
List<string> parts = new List<string>(input.Split(new char[] { ',' }));
parts.RemoveAt(2);
string output = String.Join(",", parts);
```

Comment: "1,2,3,4" is just an example. You need to *find* the value to be able to remove it.

Comment: If you want to remove the number 2 rather than the item as position 2 then change parts.RemoveAt(2) to parts.Remove(2)...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex, I would do something like:

```
- split on comma
- delete the right element
- join with comma
```

Here is a perl script that does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $toremove = 5;
my $string = "1,2,3,4,5";

my @tmp = split/,/, $string;
@tmp = grep{ $_ != $toremove }@tmp;
$string =join',', @tmp;

say $string;
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has improved since this question was posted.
I use the following regex to remove items from a csv string

```
let searchStr = "359";
let regex = new RegExp("^" + searchStr + ",?|," + searchStr);
csvStr = csvStr.replace(regex, "");
```

If the child_id is the start, middle or end, or only item it is replaced.
If the searchStr is at the start of the csvStr it and any trailing comma is replaced. Else if the searchStr is anywhere else in the csvStr it must be preceded with a comma so the searchStr and its preceding comma are replaced by an empty string.