# Javascript array.indexof not finding item in string

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
array = on,8816.32,9032.32,8990.167,9038.167,8819.389,9035.389,9059.525,8813.568,9056.726
```

The above is a string. Below is the onclick that passes a value to the function trimList.

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="9032.32" id="sendpids" onclick="trimList(9032.32)">
```

Using the function displayed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4272526/1794918. I did this.

```
    function trimList(cutThis) {

        function remove(array,to_remove)
        {
            const elements = array.split(",");
            const remove_index = elements.indexOf(to_remove);
            console.log(remove_index);
            elements.slice(1, remove_index);
            const result = elements.join(",");
            return result;
        }
        let array = checkedList.ids;
        let newList = remove(array, cutThis);
        checkedList.ids = newList;
        console.log(checkedList.ids);
    }
```

In the console log, the remove_index is always -1 which means it is not finding the variable cutThis in the array. When it rejoins the list. It removes the last item from the list and not the item submitted.

If I remove the elements = array.split(","); and just leave elements = array; I can see in the console log the number 3.

Can't seem to pull together the right combination to achieve the desired result.

On the page, there is a list of checkboxes. I have the system to create a list of values from those checkboxes. That is the array above. Now, I am trying to remove the item from the list when the box is unchecked. In this case, **9032.32** is unchecked and the string needs to be searched and the value removed from the list then a new string is created and set to the global value of checkedList.ids.

---

Comment: That initialization of `array`, if it really looks like what you posted, is not an array and it's not a string. The value of `array` would be the last number in that list of values.

Comment: I understand that. The split creates the array and the item is not found in the array. Is the problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: `elements.slice(1, remove_index);` returns a new array ... which you immediately discard since you haven't assigned the result to anything ... did you mean `elements.splice(1, remove_index);`?

Comment: Well the assignment to `array` in the code you actually posted here does not involve a string at all.

Comment: Also, `trimList(9032.32)` passes the NUMBER `9032.32` to the function - this won't match the STRING `"9032.32"` in the array ... try `const remove_index = elements.indexOf(to_remove.toString());`

Comment: For me, Looks like this is the reason @JaromandaX

Comment: It was the oversite of adding the quote marks to the original code. Thanks for catching my blunder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `checkedList.ids` is a string in the format you've stated, you have two issues

First, `elements.slice(1, remove_index);` returns a new Array, without modifying `elements` array - probably meant `elements.splice(1, remove_index);`

second, `onclick="trimList(9032.32)"` calls trimList with a Number

You want onclick="trimList('9032.32')" so indexOf will match the string

Putting it all together

```
<input type="checkbox" value="9032.32" id="sendpids" onclick="trimList('9032.32')">
```

and

```
function trimList(cutThis) {

    function remove(array,to_remove)
    {
        const elements = array.split(",");
        const remove_index = elements.indexOf(to_remove);
        console.log(remove_index);
        elements.splice(1, remove_index);
        const result = elements.join(",");
        return result;
    }
    let array = checkedList.ids;
    let newList = remove(array, cutThis);
    checkedList.ids = newList;
    console.log(checkedList.ids);
}
```

---

However, you're repeating yourself in the input tag `9032.32` ... a typo there and things won't work like they should

I would propose

```
<input type="checkbox" value="9032.32" id="sendpids" onclick="trimList(this.value)">
```

---

But, even that isn't the best solution either. I would actually suggest not using `onclick` attribute at all, instead use `element.addEventListener('click', fn)` - but it's difficult to suggest the exact code, as I have no idea of the rest of your HTML, but it could be something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="9032.32" id="sendpids">
```

and

```
document.getElementById('sendpids').addEventListener('click', trimList);

function trimList() {
    const cutThis = this.value;
    function remove(array,to_remove)
    {
        const elements = array.split(",");
        const remove_index = elements.indexOf(to_remove);
        console.log(remove_index);
        elements.splice(1, remove_index);
        const result = elements.join(",");
        return result;
    }
    let array = checkedList.ids;
    let newList = remove(array, cutThis);
    checkedList.ids = newList;
    console.log(checkedList.ids);
}
```

Comment: Jaromanda X, I appreciate the through explanation and suggestions. I used a few of them. Design is working as I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the element to be removed as number. But your array is a string array.  Change you code to something like this.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  value="9032.32"
  id="sendpids"
  onclick='trimList("9032.32")''
></input>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is the little things that trip up the process a lot of times. Looking in the wrong place. Even after I copied and pasted it into the question here. I did not catch the quote marks were missing. I will look for them the next time. My IDE could not catch that for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Split gives a string array. You need to convert your number to string in order to find the index.

```
let array = 'on,8816.32,9032.32,8990.167,9038.167,8819.389,9035.389,9059.525,8813.568,9056.726';

let splitArray = array.split(',');
let index = splitArray.indexOf(9032.32.toString());
console.log(index);
```

Comment: The reason that I did not use this answer is that the array will always change. It is not a constant set of numbers. This part (9032.32.toString()); needs to be like (cutThis.toString());

Comment: Of course that is implied. I was just trying to show you the problem in your example. You have to do yourVal.toString()